# Invocar función de PostgreSQL desde Laravel

Tags: laravel, postgresql

Tengo una función en BD de PostgreSql llamada `fn_envio(_param1, _param2, _param3, _param4)` los primeros tres parámetros son `integer` el cuarto es `character varying`

Al ejecutar la función desde la misma BD no tengo ningún problema, cuando la ejecuto desde Laravel siempre me se va por la parte de la `EXCEPTION` no tengo la certeza de estar invocando de forma correcta la función:

```
$string = "select * from fn_envio(".$param1.",".$param2.",".$param3.",'');";
$sql = DB::select($string);
```

Si alguien pudiera apoyarme se lo agradecería.

Comment: Podrías poner qué error obtienes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Observaciones**:

De forma inicial las funciones se pueden invocar bajo la sintaxis de:

```
SELECT nombre_funcion(valor1, valorN)
```

Por lo tanto esta sintaxis no es correcta:

```
select * from fn_envio(................
```

Pues así estás indicando que el nombre de la tabla es la propia función

Además tampoco es una buena idea que pases las variables dentro del cuerpo de la consulta, esto supone un riesgo de seguridad.

**Caso 1**

Entonces podemos considerar realizarlo de esta forma:

```
DB::select('SELECT fn_envio(?, ?, ?)', [$param1, $param2, $param3]);
```

Donde como notas:

- En el mismo `SELECT` invocamos a la función y donde deben ir los argumentos colocamos marcadores de parámetros con signos de interrogación.
- Finalmente fuera del cuerpo de la propia consulta, pasamos un array con las variables que harán *binding* con los marcadores antes mencionados.
- [Ejecutar *raw queries*](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database#running-queries)
- [Invocación de funciones en PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-syntax-calling-funcs.html)

**Caso 2**

O si planeas usar la función para *darle algún formato* a los datos que obtienes  puedes hacerlo de esta forma:

```
DB::select('SELECT columna1, fn_envio(columnaN) FROM tabla');
```